# Is there a verb that means "to make someone realise"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm writing a sentence that I believe would sound and read better if there was a verb for it.

> The stress management program both decreased additional cardiac events, and made them realise what really causes their stress, and with this, how to cope with their stress.

Comment: What sentence are you writing for which context? Can you include it in your question?

Comment: @Rathony edited!

Comment: "...and *enlightened* them as to what really causes their stress..." or *educated* or *informed*.

Comment: "... and informed them of what really causes..."

Comment: Thanks! I also tried "The stress management program succeeded in both a smaller amount of cardiac events, and helped patients realise and approach the root of their anxiety. "

Comment: *...and **taught** them*

Comment: Pound it into their heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlightened

> To give information to; inform or instruct.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enlightened

So in your context

> The stress management program both decreased additional cardiac
>   events, and **enlightened** them as to what really causes their stress, and
>   with this, how to cope with their stress.

Comment: Basically what @Rathony said, but in answer form. Thanks! Now I can mark this question as "Answered"

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[elucidate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/elucidate)**:

> To make clear or plain, especially by explanation; clarify